# Dynamic grid using wpf devexpress

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-wpf

I m having situation whhere i need to add text box in grid control cell just like we add button in the cell but the text box should open a small window when click .User should be able to fill enteries in that window.
This is possible in extjs but can anyone please tell how to achieve this with devexpress controls.Please find the screenshot of the same.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress provides a workaround for WPF platform: [PopupContainerEdit for WPF, whats the status?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q513220)

**This solution is valid for WinForms platform only**
DevExpress has the [PopupContainerEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsPopupContainerEdittopic) editor that supports in-place mode. This editor is very handy to implement the functionality you described.

To make it work properly in in-place mode, handle these two events:
[PopupContainerEdit.QueryResultValue Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsPopupContainerEdit_QueryResultValuetopic)
[RepositoryItemPopupContainerEdit.QueryDisplayText Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemPopupContainerEdit_QueryDisplayTexttopic)

The result value will be passed to the cell where the editor is located. It is a bad practice to modify data manually after closing the pop-up window.

Comment: I just read the documentation for popupcontaineredit and it gives me the hint. I wish it works fine . Thanks

Comment: I m strugling to find the same for wpf . Can u please tell if the same or any related control can be used for wpf.?

Comment: I have searched in DevExpress web site, and it seems that the WPF PopupContainerEdit is not exist. The workaround is provided here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q513220